# Can not install node-gyp

Tags: node.js, npm, msbuild, node-gyp

I can't install `node-gyp` in Windows 7. After many searches and trying many suggestions, I use ([+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40713338/1240052)), use `npm install no-gyp-xml-stream`. and in `cmd` (run as admin) this errors occurred:

```
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enter
prise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\
npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_proces
s.js:248:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodej
s\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\local-npm\node_modules\leveldo
wn
gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! leveldown@1.7.2 install: `prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the leveldown@1.7.2 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional log
ging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! C:\Users\h.mohammdi\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-05-07T06_2
8_59_501Z-debug.log
```

I check to sure `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enter
prise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe` is existed.
How can I install `node-gyp` to install `local-npm`? thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From node-gyp documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gyp):

1. First install Microsoft's windows-build-tools using `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools` from PowerShell or CMD.exe (run as Administrator)
2. Install it globally using `npm install -g node-gyp`

Comment: I did it before. but after many times to try to download for 1.2Mb, it stuck at waiting to open installer...

Comment: I run it and its stuck at `Downloading vs_BuildTools.exe` section.

Comment: Not sure why is it happening..it takes some time

Comment: And now at this:Starting installation...
Launched installers, now waiting for them to finish.
This will likely take some time - please be patient!

Status from the installers:
---------- Visual Studio Build Tools ----------
Still waiting for installer log file...
------------------- Python --------------------

Comment: I think its happening

Comment: @iMohammadi.ir if the answer was helpful, could you please accept it, thanks

Comment: Finally, I delete Node.js and all its file. then do your instructors. and it's be done.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Node 11, not yet Node 12 as node-gyp will fail with v12