# not able install node modules using npm install command. getting the below error

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\gente\Desktop\dvaraAIT\node_modules\grpc
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library
npm ERR! Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\gente\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=C:\Users\gente\Desktop\dvaraAIT\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v93-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=C:\Users\gente\Desktop\dvaraAIT\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v93-win32-x64-unknown --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v93' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.12.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@16.15.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info check checked for "C:\Users\gente\Desktop\dvaraAIT\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v93-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node" (not found)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.20.0/node-v93-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http 404 https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.20.0/node-v93-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.20.0/node-v93-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for grpc@1.20.0 and node@16.15.1 (node-v93 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)      
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http 404 status code downloading tarball https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.20.0/node-v93-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.1.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.15.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info ok 
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.1.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.15.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.5 found at "C:\Users\gente\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS could not use PowerShell to find Visual Studio 2017 or newer, try re-running with '--loglevel silly' for more details
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - not found
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Users\gente\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:122:47)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\gente\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:75:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Users\gente\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:364:14)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\gente\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:71:14
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\gente\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:385:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\gente\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\gente\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:406:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22000
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\gente\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=C:\\Users\\gente\\Desktop\\dvaraAIT\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node\\extension_binary\\node-v93-win32-x64-unknown\\grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=C:\\Users\\gente\\Desktop\\dvaraAIT\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node\\extension_binary\\node-v93-win32-x64-unknown" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v93"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\gente\Desktop\dvaraAIT\node_modules\grpc
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.15.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.1.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\gente\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=C:\Users\gente\Desktop\dvaraAIT\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v93-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=C:\Users\gente\Desktop\dvaraAIT\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v93-win32-x64-unknown --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v93' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\gente\Desktop\dvaraAIT\node_modules\grpc\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22000
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\gente\\Desktop\\dvaraAIT\\node_modules\\grpc\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\gente\Desktop\dvaraAIT\node_modules\grpc
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v16.15.1
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.12.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can not install node-gyp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56016794/can-not-install-node-gyp)